# From old tweets get their timezone

Tags: python, twitter, twitter4j

I have a bunch of old tweets, which include post time, userID, tweetID and content.
What I want to do from them is deciding their timezone, such as EST or PST.

I searched online, but it seems even though with Twitter API, you can only get this information for new tweets. 
Is there anyway to do this?

So I found this TwitterAPI: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show
It seems that I can use UserID to get their state, and then I can decide the timezone. But I bumped into a lot of questions when I tried to use this API via python (I can not even install httplib2, oauth2)

I also looked for Twitter4J package, but could find an answer.

So can anyone please tell me if this is possible?If so, is there any method that I can use?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Make a call to [`/statuses/show/:tweetID`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid). The response will have the timezone in the `time_zone` attribute.